# Where the execution plan builds for default store procedures in sqlserver?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

We have Inbuilt store procedures in SQl server, I want to know where the execution plan builds for default store procedures? for exame : Sp_who2.

Answer (score 0):

The execution plans for system stored procedures are stored in the same place as normal stored procedures. You can access them using something like:

```
USE Master;
SELECT c.plan_handle, q.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS c
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(c.plan_handle) AS q
WHERE q.objectid =  OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.sp_who');
```

I suspect that you might actually be after the definition, because needing the execution plan of these strikes me as a little odd, because the main reason for needing an execution plan is performance tuning. So assuming that you are after the procedure definition, you can get this using:

```
USE Master;
SELECT [definition]
FROM sys.system_sql_modules
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.sp_who');
```

Or in SQL Server management studio, you can find the procedures under `Databases > Programability > Stored Procedures > System Stored Procedures`, then right click and choose modify:

[image]

Comment: Hi GarethD, Thank you for your reply.  I understood well with your example. So Sqlserver default(inbuilt) stored procedures also having plans in plan cache? please guide me

Comment: The first query in my answer will give you the query plan from the cache.

Comment: Thank you. Got it.